# How do you get the pagecontextPath.request.contextpath from JavaScript using spring controller?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

`window.location.href=location.origin+"/apreizspring/teammember"`

apreizspring is my project name. I want to replace this by using `pagecontext`. Can anyone provide me a solution?

Comment: if the javascript code is on jsp you can use jstl to include it. if it is on javascript file then you need to pass the value to set the contextpath from jsp to the js.

Comment: it is in javascript file....can you provide me some examples

Comment: Checkout my answer for the implementation with jstl

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript file:

```
window.location.href = requestContextPath + "/teammember"
```

Lets say, your javascript file is named `temp.js`

In jsp :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<script>
    var requestContextPath = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}';
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'temp.js'></script>
```

Comment: i want to replace apreizspring by ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Comment: updated the code now.. try it out.. the context path returned by jstl will be in this format `http://<server>:<port>/<context>`

Comment: how can i define requestContextPath in external script